# replace column value of nth column with a list of dataframes where value matches criteria

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sapply

If I have the following list of dataframes:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3), y2=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1), y2=c(6,5,4))
d3 <- data.frame(y1=c(6,5,4), y2=c(3,2,1))
d4 <- data.frame(y1=c(9,9,9), y2=c(8,8,8))

my.list <- list(d1, d2, d3, d4)

my.list
[[1]]
  y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6

[[2]]
  y1 y2
1  3  6
2  2  5
3  1  4

[[3]]
  y1 y2
1  6  3
2  5  2
3  4  1

[[4]]
  y1 y2
1  9  8
2  9  8
3  9  8
```

how do I replace values in the second column where the number is greater than 5 with "greater than 5" i.e.

```
my.list
[[1]]
  y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  'greater than five'

[[2]]
  y1 y2
1  3  'greater than five'
2  2  5
3  1  4

[[3]]
  y1 y2
1  6  3
2  5  2
3  4  1

[[4]]
  y1 y2
1  9  'greater than five'
2  9  'greater than five'
3  9  'greater than five'
```

I know I can test for such cases by doing something like:

```
sapply(sapply(my.list, "[[", 2), function(x) x > 5)
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

but cannot work out how to replace the original value when the test is true.

any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go for `replace` in base R:

```
col <- 2
lapply(my.list, function(x) 
      data.frame(cbind(x[,-col], replace(x[,col], x[,col]>5, "greater than five"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `transform` with `lapply`

```
lapply(my.list, transform, y2 = replace(y2, y2>5, "greater than 5"))
#[1]]
#  y1             y2
#1  1              4
#2  2              5
#3  3 greater than 5

#[[2]]
#  y1             y2
#1  3 greater than 5
#2  2              5
#3  1              4

#[[3]]
#  y1 y2
#1  6  3
#2  5  2
#3  4  1

#[[4]]
#  y1             y2
#1  9 greater than 5
#2  9 greater than 5
#3  9 greater than 5
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
my.list %>%
    map(~mutate(., y2 = replace(y2, y2 >5, "greater than 5")))
```